# How to "reset" picker from the ViewModel - Xamarin iOS and MvvmCross

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

This is Xamarin iOS and MvvmCross. I'm having problems resetting picker from the viewmodel. I'm binding to a picker's SelectedItem. When the view is loaded, picker shows a placeholder:

[image]

Then when I select an option from the picker, it shows the selected option:

[image]

Is there anyway to reset the picker from viewmodel and force it to show placeholder as on startup? I tried set the SelectedItem property I bind to to null, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try setting the index to ```-1```. I believe that is the value for Xamarin to display the title.

Comment: The problem is I'm using MvxPickerViewModel and there is no SelectedIndex property. I'm using this approach - http://www.karimmastrobuono.com/blog/2019/1/9/uipickerview-and-mvvmcross

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, set the `SelectedName` to the first item to reset the picker's index. Then Set it to null to show the TextField's placeholder:

```
ClearCommand = new MvxCommand(() =>
{
    SelectedName = NamesCollection[0];
    SelectedName = null;
});
```

Here is the effect:

[image]